# Calculate lookat vector from position and Euler angles

Tags: opengl, camera, frame-rate

I've implemented an FPS style camera, with the camera consisting of a position vector, and Euler angles pitch and yaw (x and y rotations).
After setting up the projection matrix, I then translate to camera coordinates by rotating, then translating to the inverse of the camera position:

```
// Load projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

// Set perspective
gluPerspective(m_fFOV, m_fWidth/m_fHeight, m_fNear, m_fFar);

// Load modelview matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

// Position camera
glRotatef(m_fRotateX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
glRotatef(m_fRotateY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
glTranslatef(-m_vPosition.x, -m_vPosition.y, -m_vPosition.z);
```

Now I've got a few viewports set up, each with its own camera, and from every camera I render the position of the other cameras (as a simple box). 
I'd like to also draw the view vector for these cameras, except I haven't a clue how to calculate the lookat vector from the position and Euler angles. 
I've tried to multiply the original camera vector (0, 0, -1) by a matrix representing the camera rotations
then adding the camera position to the transformed vector, but that doesn't work at all (most probably because I'm way off base):

```
vector v1(0, 0, -1);
matrix m1 = matrix::IDENTITY;
m1.rotate(m_fRotateX, 0, 0);
m1.rotate(0, m_fRotateY, 0);

vector v2 = v1 * m1;
v2 = v2 + m_vPosition; // add camera position vector

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3fv(m_vPosition);
glVertex3fv(v2);
glEnd();
```

What I'd like is to draw a line segment from the camera towards the lookat direction.
I've looked all over the place for examples of this, but can't seem to find anything.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just curious, are you doing anything to handle gimbal lock?

Comment: No, I know it's there, lurking ;) I will try quaternions later, but I'd really like to figure this out first.

Comment: When you're rotating your camera, you're actually rotating the whole world in opposite direction.. So when you apply the same transformation to the vector instead of moving it with camera you rotate it even more in the opposite direction, try rotating with inverse matrix of matrix you use to rotate your view..

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Applying the matrix transformations in the correct order (inverse of the camera transformation itself) solves my problem!

Comment: If you use two angle-axis rotations as in the example... No gimbal lock exists; or rather it exists but is intended. You do not expect the FPS camera to freely rotate in any direction. The problem is only free form rotation with euler angles.

Answer (score 4):

I just figured it out. When I went back to add the answer, I saw that Ivan had just told me the same thing :)

Basically, to draw the camera vector, I do this:

```
glPushMatrix();

// Apply inverse camera transform
glTranslatef(m_vPosition.x, m_vPosition.y, m_vPosition.z);
glRotatef(-m_fRotateY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
glRotatef(-m_fRotateX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

// Then draw the vector representing the camera
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 0, -10);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

This draws a line from the camera position for 10 units in the lookat direction.